# Need a black filler bar spanning the width of my website on bottom and top, and must be expandable

Tags: html, css

Hey everyone.  I am trying to create a black bar, the size of the footer to extend from one side of a page to another (pretty much to fill in the white space and make it look like my footer extends to each side of the screen.  I cannot do this because I have already used an image in the body section of  my CSS

```
body {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  padding:0px;
  background-color:#FFF;
  font-family: calibri;
  background-image:url(images/item9HeaderSideFiller.gif);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

*I'm pretty much doing the same thing with the header, but the black line is much smaller.

Please check out the site http://item9andthemadhatters.com/

This will make it easier to understand what I am trying to do.

I know this is probably an easy fix, but I'm new with html.  Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Well I know it is not an efficient solution but try to use this #footer{margin-left:-17px; width:1121px} and I understand that you are new to html but your code needs improvements and thats why i am tell you an inefficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED. 
Move the `#footer` outside the `#wrap`, and add another div for the background.

```
<div id="wrap">
    ...
</div>
<div id="footer-wrap">
    <div id="footer">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer-wrap { background:#000; }
#footer { width:954px; margin:auto; }
```

`#footer-wrap` would get the background styles.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I did all of this and now I'm trying to extend the footer wrap to fit the width of the page.  Here's my code:

Comment: #footerWrap {
 background-color:#000;
 width: auto;
 
}

#footer {
 
 text-align:center;
 width:965px;
 height:150px;
 background-color:#000;
 border:#000 inset medium;
}

Comment: If you did this right, the #footer-wrap will fill up the whole page. Are you working in a dev environment? The link you gave doesnt look updated.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  I'm working in dreamweaver.  I've just uploaded the whole site.  I just need a black bar across the bottom essentially.  I would have used a background image in the body but I am already doing that for the top line.  Any other suggestions please let me know, I think think would make the footer look a lot better.

Comment: hold the phones!  It works now.  THanks a bunch for the help everyone!